# Get data from file(image\splash.png) failed

Tags: eclipse, cocos2d-x-2.x

I've been learning cocos2d-x by developing a flappy bird. The version is 2.2.3.

My program can run on VS. But when I build it in eclipse and install the apk to an android device, the App flash back and the logcat says: Get data from file(image\splash.png) failed.

I found the code in cpp file:

```
std::string splash_path = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->fullPathForFilename("image\\splash.png");
CCSprite *background = CCSprite::create(splash_path.c_str());
```

And all the images and sounds are in the assets folder.

Anyone can tell me how to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: correct your tag, this is not android, and if this is NDK, you are attempting the wrong way, NDK is for special purpose only, not for common

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by changing the code to:

```
std::string splash_path = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->fullPathForFilename("image/splash.png");
```

just replace the '\\' to '/'.

Comment: \\ slash is for windows only, on all unix/liunx based system, all file paths should be referred as / . And this also works on windows based system, so this is the suggestive method.